# Is there any AOL Contacts API?

Tags: oauth, aol

Is there any oAuth based AOL contacts API available just like google contacts, yahoo contacts and live contacts APIs.
If so then can anybody redirect me to their link please?
I cannot seem to find any AOL contacts API info on their website.

Answer (score 2):

AOL has had a "Coming Soon" page up for that feature for quite a while: http://dev.aol.com/api/addressbook/comingsoon

We're not really sure when they'll release it, but I'm keeping an eye on it so I'll let you know whenever they do.

Shameless plug: Come check out http://www.CloudSponge.com if you want a quick solution for AOL.  It's a single point of integration for AOL Contacts, Yahoo Contacts, Gmail Contacts, Hotmail/MSN/Windows Live Contacts, Outlook, Plaxo and OS X Address book.

Lemme know what you think, StackOverflow customers are our favorite.

Answer (score 1):

A Bit strange, if you go to twitter and try using the import tool for AOL it shows that they do have a system for it just no information for it anywhere.